# How to publish open source library to my nexus server with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, nexus

I want to publish an open source library to my own remote nexus repo. I try to change .sbt files for the library but `sbt publish` still tries to release using the normal sonatype nexus repo. `sbt publish-local` works fine for a different local project so I think that maybe I can deploy this lib without changing the .sbt files to my remote nexus.

Can I publish this lib only with added credentials in the command line?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question but what is about cloning the open source project's repository build and publish it locally with 'publishLocal'

Comment: But my nexus repo is remote and I want to automate this process.

Comment: Is it your own library or a third party open source library?

Comment: Third part open source library. I clone for git and try to deploy previous version.